# Placing Custom WPF Control inside of a StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom WPF control and place it inside of a `StackPanel` in my XAML file. I originally made a custom `UserControl` and got the following error message:

```
A value of type 'CustomControl' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.
```

I tried changing my custom control from a `UserControl` to a `UIElement`, but I still get this message. How do I make a custom control that I can place inside of the `StackPanel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you creating the CustomControl? Make sure it is inheriting from UserControl.

I just created a new project called "TestProj" - right clicked in the solution explorer Add=>UserControl and named it CustomControl.

I was able to insert it via the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProj"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:CustomControl/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6):

Restart Visual Studio. The XAML designer is a notoriously sensitive beast.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you're subclassing another control class, but your .xaml.cs file is still subclassing UserControl.